# Why does the hot side of the JWST seem so much hotter than any other satellite?

Tags: heat

The JWST has a hot side of 125$^\circ$C, according to NASA. Is it the only space vessel to get that hot?  This site talks about many aspects concerning the temperature of satellites, but none of them mention such inhospitably high values. Indeed, we often read that the Hubble enjoys an "earth-like" temperature. That is not the most scientific of terms, but it is a phrase often repeated on official web pages.  Is the big difference caused by the JWST being in more absolute vacuum?

Comment: Hubble has a thermal blanket to stabilize the temperature. It keeps the mirrors near (Earth) room temperature, which does not affect the sensors, unlike the IR that Webb uses. And Hubble goes in and out of direct sun as it orbits, unlike Webb that is out at a Lagrange point. All very different…

Answer (score 4):

An object (such as the earth) that is at the same distance from the Sun as the Earth, has emissive and absorbtive properties similar to the Earth (such as being made of the things the Earth is made of), and is rotating or has internal fluid flow or some other means to distribute heat around it (like the Earth does) will be at the same approximate temperature as the Earth.

However, an object that is not rotating, and which is a pretty good insulator, will heat up to a highish temperature on the sun-facing side, while the side facing away from the Sun will cool down to a much lower temperature.  The exact temperatures achieved will depend on the geometry and material properties of the object. The slight difference between vacuum in low earth orbit and vacuum in interplanetary space does not matter much.

The JWST is shaped like a flat thermal-insulating blanket with almost all of the satellite on the shaded side. Many spacecraft are not like that. Satellites in Low Earth Orbit have a day-night cycle, which evens out the temperature. Others may rotate, which also evens it out, or just be designed to keep a fairly even temperature -- during the flight to the Moon, the Apollo spacecraft deliberately did a "barbecue roll" to prevent freezing on one side and cooking on the other.

There definitely are hotter spacecraft -- the Parker Solar Probe is similar to the JWST in that it is a spacecraft that has a flattish insulating shield of which one side is kept towards the Sun. However, it flies much, much closer to the Sun than the Earth and the JWST are and the Sun-ward side of the spacecraft reaches 1,377 deg C, much hotter than the JWST. To survive this temperature, its shield is made of ultra high temperature graphite foam.

Answer (score -1):

The giant sunshield blocks the side view- the observatory bus sees, instead of dark space at ~3 K, reflective film, which kinda looks like… the Sun. Since the film itself is just inert plastic (plus coating) that can take the heat, we’ll limit the discussion to the bus (box, its appendages, systems and functions etc.).

You can work out the numbers: for any point on the bus, how much heat source (Sun, and to a lesser extent other bodies) will it see over a spherical view, how much is ‘other spacecraft’ (at temperature TBD), and how much is heat sink (dark space, again ~3 K)? Each point then gives some equilibrium temperature value; integrate over the entire spacecraft to get a heat map, then… recalculate, with spacecraft temperatures now at some estimates you hadn’t had before. For something that really matters, you probably need to do another iteration. For something $X billion, you need iterations of checks of iterations of triple-checks, with multiple cases including some outlier contingencies.

All in all, the JW hot side sees very little cold space, instead seeing the rest of the hot side. The bus is hotter than other missions for the same reason you might let your several, big dogs get in bed with you on a cold night. You now have mammal against you (~XX degrees), not room air (palpably fewer deg.). This is true with or without the blanket.

Other space vessels use, ideally, their backsides (from the Sun’s point of view) as their radiator, to cool themselves from… the Sun’s view, plus internal generation. In some cases the definition of ‘backside’ is never set, or that side is already needed for something else. Those spacecraft use whatever surfaces they have free, at lower efficiency. Here, the JW bus has no backside radiator, because it’s taken by the science part.